# Find the Sharepoint application server based on Sharepoint Databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sharepoint

I'm doing some cleanup in my SQL Server farm and I found on one of our SQL servers (2012) several databases that I believe belong to a Sharepoint server.

No one knows in the company what is the SP that is linked to it.

I'm don't have much experience with Sharepoint.

Can you please help me with some direct queries in the Sharepoint database - Where can I find a URL for the SP ? Or Where is the Sharepoint Application server name (It is not on the same box as the database server).

I want to gather information before I'll recommend to delete those databases.

Thanks in advance,

Roni.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the sessions on that database:

```
SELECT host_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions
WHERE database_id = db_id('yourSharepointDatabaseName');
```

If something is using the database, the client host name will show up here.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, however, there's no activity at all on these database at all, so no active/sleeping spids. 
I suspect it's legacy server.

Comment: If you want to monitor usage over time, you need to set up something like audit or a XE session that captures accesses. I have a post here about the topic: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/20/tracking-table-usage-and-identifying-unused-objects/ Hope it helps

Comment: No, I just want to find inside the Sharepoint database table a direction what could be the name of the Sharepoint application server, in order to know if that server is in use or not. I don't want to monitor usage, as I suspects it's not being used at all.